# CSS causing different size pages

Tags: html, css, size

```
    body {
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    p {
        background-color: white;
    }
    #content {
        #header {
            width: 350px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            left: 500px;
            top: 5px;
            border-bottom: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-color: #E0E0E0;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: calibri;
        }
        #footer {
            padding-left: 20px;
            width: 1495px;
            height: 17px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
        }

        .navbar-item {
            /*This is a class to seperate the different links in the footer nav bar, it specifies a wdith for each item so they have some space between the links*/

            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 350px;
            height: 17px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
        :hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: blue;
        }
```

The above code sets out the correct layout for my home page, but when I use the exact same CSS code for another page everything is smaller for some reason. I don't see why it can create the page correctly for one page, but when the exact same document is used for another page it changes the look of the page. All the boxes used are smaller.

Comment: The css seems a bit wrong #content { never closes and :hover is not a valid selector on it's own. Did you mean .navbar-item:hover? 
You need to give more information for someone to answer I think. Like if there is other css overriding the above in a different page etc.

Comment: There is only one CSS file that is being used for the entire website, I designed it using the index (home) page, and this page is fine, exactly the way I want it. But when I have used the exact same CSS document for another page, everything is smaller, around 25% smaller, but because its the same document the sizes should be the same

Comment: If there is no other CSS affecting the page, either external or inline, I don't think there is a way that this can be happening, other than you zooming out your browser somehow by mistake.
I would fix the CSS though so that the selectors close correctly. (i..e the #content { ... 
Maybe double-check that there is no other CSS (either external or inline) that may affect your elements.
You can debug your page using chrome developer tools by opening the page in chrome and looking for developer tools as described here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @klikas `:hover` is actually valid on its own. It means "anything hovered over". And the nested structure means it's probably LESS or something; the OP should have mentioned that though.

Comment: @user3257023 If you have two similar pages and everything is smaller on one than on the other, chances are one of your pages is zoomed. Check that first.

Comment: @MrLister you are correct about :hover. My bad. The question didn't mention anything about LESS/SASS but you may be right that there may be a pre-processor in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

p {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#content, #header {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

#footer {
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 1495px;
  height: 17px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.navbar-item {
/*This is a class to seperate the different links in the footer nav bar, it specifies a wdith for each item so they have some space between the links*/
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-item:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: blue;
}
```

Since your `#header` was inside of your `#content` brackets I just assumed you wanted to apply the same styles to each.

Hope this is what you meant.